# How do I alternate a UICollectiveViewCell's background color based on row?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I know this is fairly easy for UITableViewCells but I'm not sure how to approach this using a UICollectionView.

EDIT. Pictures for clarification. Text content of the cells are not the same here but they should be.
In landscape:

[image]

In portrait:

[image]

I tried to naively switch the color of my cell's text label with the cell's background color based on the index path's row property in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method. However Index Path's row property isn't really a row in UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: Can you go into detail on the pattern you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Is the number of items on each row constant? Are you allowing rotation, and if so, does that change the number of items on each row?

Comment: @0x7fffffff First one is one color, second row in my grid is a different, third is the same as the first, etc.

Comment: @rdelmar Yes except for maybe the last row. And yes, rotation changes the number of items on each row.

Comment: @s1m0n do you know how item and row differ besides which view they are supposed to be used with? They seem to always return the same value.

Comment: Did you implement any of the methods of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`?

Comment: Subclass CollectionViewFlowLayout and colorise it from inside there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither the collection view nor its layout will tell you a “row number” for items.  You have to compute it yourself.

If all of your measurements are uniform (which is the case if you didn't implement any `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods), you can compute it pretty easily.

There are a few places you could do the computation and assign the color.  I'm going to show you the “proper” place to do it: in the layout manager.

The [“Knowing When to Subclass the Flow Layout” section of the *Collection View Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW4) tells you the basic things you need to do, but it's pretty bare bones, so I'll walk you through it.

Note: since `layoutAttributes` is a pretty cumbersome identifier, I usually use `pose` instead.

#### `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` subclass

First of all, we need a way to pass the background color from the layout manager to the cell.  The right way to do that is by subclassing `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`.  The interface just adds one property:

```
@interface MyLayoutAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *backgroundColor;

@end
```

The implementation needs to implement the `NSCopying` protocol:

```
@implementation MyLayoutAttributes

- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    MyLayoutAttributes *copy = [super copyWithZone:zone];
    copy.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
    return copy;
}

@end
```

#### `UICollectionViewCell` subclass

Next, the cell needs to use that `backgroundColor` attributes.  You probably already have a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass.  You need to implement `applyLayoutAttributes:` in your subclass, like this:

```
@implementation MyCell

- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(MyLayoutAttributes *)pose {
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:pose];
    if (!self.backgroundView) {
        self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }
    self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = pose.backgroundColor;
}

@end
```

#### `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass

Now you need to make a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that uses `MyLayoutAttributes` instead of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, and sets the `backgroundColor` of each `MyLayoutAttributes` correctly.  Let's define the interface to have a property which is the array of colors to assign to rows:

```
@interface MyLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *rowColors;

@end
```

The first thing we need to do in our implementation is specify what layout attributes class we want it to use:

```
@implementation MyLayout

+ (Class)layoutAttributesClass {
    return [MyLayoutAttributes class];
}
```

Next, we need to override two methods of `UICollectionViewLayout` to set the `backgroundColor` property of each pose.  We call on `super` to get the set of poses, and then use a helper method to set the background colors:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *poses = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    [self assignBackgroundColorsToPoses:poses];
    return poses;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyLayoutAttributes *pose = (MyLayoutAttributes *)[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self assignBackgroundColorsToPoses:@[ pose ]];
    return pose;
}
```

Here's the method that actually assigns the background colors:

```
- (void)assignBackgroundColorsToPoses:(NSArray *)poses {
    NSArray *rowColors = self.rowColors;
    int rowColorsCount = rowColors.count;
    if (rowColorsCount == 0)
        return;

    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.sectionInset;
    CGFloat lineSpacing = self.minimumLineSpacing;
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.itemSize.height + lineSpacing;
    for (MyLayoutAttributes *pose in poses) {
        CGFloat y = pose.frame.origin.y;
        NSInteger section = pose.indexPath.section;
        y -= section * (insets.top + insets.bottom) + insets.top;
        y += section * lineSpacing; // Fudge: assume each prior section had at least one cell
        int row = floorf(y / rowHeight);
        pose.backgroundColor = rowColors[row % rowColorsCount];
    }
}
```

Note that this method makes several assumptions:

- It assumes the scroll direction is vertical.
- It assumes all items are the same size.
- It assumes all sections have the same insets and line spacings.
- It assumes every section has at least one item.

The reason for the last assumption is that all rows in a section are followed by the minimum line spacing, **except** for the last row, which is followed by the bottom section inset.  I need to know how many rows preceded the current item's row.  I try to do that by dividing the Y coordinate by the height of a row… but the last row of each section is shorter than the others.  Hence the fudging.

#### Applying Your New Classes

Anyway, now we need to put these new classes to use.

First, we need to use `MyLayout` instead of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.  If you're setting up your collection view in code, just create an instead of `MyLayout` and assign it to the collection view.  If you're setting things up in a storyboard, find the collection view's layout (it is in the storyboard outliner as a child of the collection view) and set its custom class to `MyLayout`.

Second, we need to assign an array of colors to the layout.  If you're using a storyboard, you probably want to do this in `viewDidLoad`.  You could ask the collection view for its layout and then cast it to `MyLayout`.  I prefer to use an outlet of the proper type, connected to the layout object in the storyboard.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.layout.rowColors = @[
        [UIColor lightGrayColor],
        [UIColor cyanColor],
    ];
}
```

#### Result

If you got everything set up correctly, you'll get a result like this:

[image: portrait screen shot]

and in landscape orientation it looks like this:

[image: landscape screen shot]

I've put my test project [in this github repository](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-18317405-collectionViewAlternatingRows).

Comment: Very well explained answer !

Answer (score 1):

I don' think there's any good general way to do this without subclassing the flow layout. For a more specific case, you can use integer math combined with the modulus operator to get "rows" from the indexPath. So, if you had 5 items on each row, you could return either 0 or 1 from this expression:

```
NSInteger rowTest = (indexPath.row / 5) % 2;
```

Just test this value, and change your color accordingly. Of course, you'll have to change the expression on rotation since you'll have a different number of items on each row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the indexPath.section property to get a row.

Comment: I could do this though I'm looking for a way to this in a reusable way that doesn't involve changing my existing sections and the number of items in a row changes based on rotation.

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean. Can you please elaborate your comment.

Comment: Imagine I have nine cells in my collection view and in landscape it is displayed in a 3 by 3 grid. I could have 3 cells per section but when I rotate it to portrait my collective view is drawn as a two column grid with one cell missing in the last row of each section and then the color would not be based on row.

Comment: Does it mean that the color once assigned to a cell should remain the same no matter what orientation?

Comment: No the color is indirectly related to orientation if an orientation changes the number of cells per row. I added pics.

Answer (score 0):

### Something like this should do it.  May take some tweaking, etc.  Assuming that you are not using sections which would have to have some changes..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@end
```

---

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define WIDTH   200
#define HEIGHT  200
#define XMARGIN 50
#define YMARGIN 20

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int numberOfCols;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib* cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell"];    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 6;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Row number %d",indexPath.row);
    int rem = (indexPath.row / self.numberOfCols);
    NSLog(@"col number %d", rem);
    if ( rem % 2 == 0 )
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.numberOfCols = (collectionView.frame.size.width - (XMARGIN*2)) / (WIDTH);
    NSLog(@"Number of cols is %d",self.numberOfCols);

    return CGSizeMake(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(XMARGIN, YMARGIN, XMARGIN, YMARGIN);
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is yucky, subject to breaking if there's a header, but at least this will get you going.  In cellForItemAtIndexPath...

```
// dequeue cell

CGFloat originY = cell.frame.origin.y;

// if there are headers, then grab the header view and...
originY -= header.bounds.size.height * indexPath.section;

NSInteger row = originY / cell.bounds.size.height;
BOOL evenRow = row%2 == 0;
```