# Background color of cell with UITextView in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is something i have been trying for past few days but not able to make a breakthrough

I have a textView in each cell of a UICollectionView.What i would like to do is to have a different color for only the first row of the grid.

I have used the solution from the below link from rob mayoff and it works fine for a label but not a textView
[How do I alternate a UICollectiveViewCell's background color based on row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317405/how-do-i-alternate-a-uicollectiveviewcells-background-color-based-on-row/28069351#28069351)

I can see that the UITextView is superseding the UICollectionViewCell properties.
Any idea how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by UITextArea?

Comment: sorry man . i meant UITextView. i have made the edits

Answer (score 0):

i think i made some progress here. i have set the background color of the textview to clearColor . in this way, the color of the the collectionviewcell shows up.

I am not sure whether this is the correct approach