# iOS Swift - UICollectionView - Sections different background color

Tags: ios, swift, background, header, uicollectionview

Is there a way to set different background colors to UICollectionView's header and the content view?

I want my collection's header background color - clearColor and the content background to be white.

Thank you!

Comment: `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` actually manipulates its subviews' bounds, so the background of the collection view isn't actually moving. You could check for `contentOffset` and detect when you go to the next section.

Comment: Check out this. A very well explained answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317405/how-do-i-alternate-a-uicollectiveviewcells-background-color-based-on-row

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `UICollectionViewCell` background color within `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and the section header background within `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return   2
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }
        return headerView
    }
```

[image]